# Return response from a Handler Func

Tags: go, goroutine

I am fairly new to golang and in one of the handler functions I'm collecting the data using channels from different goroutines and now wanted to return the array of result as a response object

So I have given a return type as the struct details but it's throwing an error

if this is not the way to return the slice of struct as response then how can I return my results array as a response to post my request

**Error:**

```
cannot use homePage (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) []details) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to http.HandleFunc
```

**Handler Func:**

```
func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) []details{    

    var wg sync.WaitGroup    


    for _, url := range urls {  
        out, err := json.Marshal(url)
        if err != nil {
            panic (err)
        }        
        wg.Add(1)
        go do_calc(ch,client,string(out),&wg)        
    }

    fmt.Println("Returning Response")  
    go func() {
        for v := range ch {
            results = append(results, v)
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)  

    return results



}
```

Comment: `http.HandleFunc` does not expect any return value, the reason for the error is your `[]details`. You can see the docs for it here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc

Comment: Even if I remove the return value [details] it throws an error too many arguments to return have([]details)

Answer (score 7):

So, your question is two fold. Firstly the reason for the error is because if you look at the documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc) you can see that `http.HandleFunc` has the following definition.

```
func HandleFunc(pattern string, handler func(ResponseWriter, *Request))
```

Since your function has a return with `[]details` it does not meet the requirements.

So going off the other part of your question;

> if this is not the way to return the slice of struct as response then how can I return my results array as a response to post my request

To solve your problem we need to write your data back to the response, you'll notice in the arguments passed to your `HandleFunc` you have a `ResponseWriter`, where you can use the [Write()](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Write) method to return your response

Not entirely sure how you want to display your result but you could do it with JSON easy enough.

```
b, err := json.Marshal(results)
if err != nil {
    // Handle Error
}
w.Write(b)
```